# My PC suddenly has less performance

Tags: cpu, performance, power-supply, fps

This all happened around when my cat jumped off my PC case, which made it shake from side to side:

A lot of games I play now have really bad performance(used to play at 60fps with medium-high settings now maybe 10.)

I've checked that all connectors, RAM and Graphic Card are secure. I'm using the stock CPU fan and it seems to stay at a constant speed which I'm not sure if it's supposed to but since it has a 4 pin connector I assume it should.

I used RealTemp 3.7 to measure the CPU temp:

- CPU Idle Temp : 30 - 40
- while playing ex: Battle for middle earth 2 - ROTWK(pretty old game) Temp : about 80-90 and even close to a 100 but I closed the game before it ever reached it.

Basically my PC performance went downhill from around the time my cat hit my pc.

SPECS :

- CPU: Intel core i5-4590 LGA1150
- Graphic Card: GIGABYTE RADEON R9 380
- PSU: Pure Power L8 - 730W
- Motherboard: Fatality Asrock z97 Killer series
- RAM: x2 Hyper X Fury 8GB

Comment: You more or less stated it yourself - your CPU is getting way too hot. Remove the stock fan, clean the heatspreader and cooler, use a bit of new thermal compound. Make sure the coolers seated perfectly.

Comment: Basically the answer but figured it out when I reviewed my question. Thx anyways, cheers.

Comment: @K.Mallia feel free to post an answer of yourself so you can mark it as solved in 2 days and we know you no longer need help.

Comment: Good man for BFME. as patrick said, re-apply the paste. the intel default heat sinks are fairly friendly, flatheaded screwdriver to rotate and pop them open. To answer your question about 4 pin fans. They are PWM fans, they speed up and slow down the fan as the motherboard sees fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU and heat-sink did not have enough thermal paste to make a good connection between them. An extra drop was enough.